# WCF HttpClient poll ContentReadStream on an open connection?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, http, rest

I'm connecting with a WCF HttpClient to a node.js http server (express). Server-side I keep the connection open and stream data to the client. How can I poll the ContentReadStream client-side?

Comment: What I would like to do is raise an event whenever some string terminated by a newline character is received on the channel. Is this possible with the WCF HttpClient?

Answer (score 0):

Jeroen, HttpClient/HttpContent has async methods that use the new Task in .net 4.0. You should be able to use those methods for streaming.

Comment: Thnx, will be digging into TPL this weekend. So far I've been doing this in Java with the apache httpclient lib where you can spin a thread to read from the inputstream. I'll let you know if it worked out.